# Installing QGIS from non-packed file

Tags: qgis-2, installation, windows

I've been asked a question regarding installation of QGIS from an unpacked file on Windows, as the organization that wants to install it needs to run a thorough malware scan.

Currently, the installation of QGIS in standalone form requires downloading of the setup file which then proceeds to download and unpack all the QGIS files. This doesn't allow a malware scan beforehand.

Is there a way to install a "pre-unpacked" QGIS program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what platform you are on but if Windows, you can use the [osgeo4win](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) installer.  If you choose the `Advanced install` option and select the option to `Download without installing`, do your malware scan and then go back into osgeo4win and select the option to `Install from local directory`.

Once you are into the `Select Packages` window, if you only want QGIS, expand the Desktop section and select the version of QGIS you want and osgeo4win will handle the dependencies for you (this is the way I always install QGIS rather than the installer from the QGIS site).